# Suppose $H\triangleleft G$ and $H\leq K\leq G$. Show that $H\triangleleft K$ and $K/H\leq G/H$.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $H\triangleleft G$ and $H\leq K\leq G$. Show that $H\triangleleft K$ and $K/H\leq G/H$.

I thought of defining $\phi: G\rightarrow K$, $\gamma: K\rightarrow K/H$ and $\psi: K/H\rightarrow G/H$.

Then F = $\psi \circ \gamma \circ \phi (g)$ (functions under composition) is a surjective homomorphism with kernel H. From this it would follow that all of $\psi, \gamma, \phi$ are surjective homomorphisms (right?). I don't think I can conclude from all of this what I'm trying to show, can I? It seems I'm missing some logic here.

Comment: Why would you use maps to show that a certain group is a subgroup of another group ?

Comment: @Max I thought I could show inclusion that way

Comment: Usually incluson cannot be shown using injective maps (it sometimes can, obviously, but here I don't think it can)

Answer (score 1):

$H\trianglelefteq G$ means $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$ for all $g\in G$, therefore since $K\leq G$ it also holds for $g\in K$. Hence we have $H\trianglelefteq K$.

For $K/H\leq G/H$ the map $\psi: K/H\rightarrow G/H$ is injective by definition of $\psi$, i.e. $\psi(kH) = kH$.

Comment: But giving an injective map doesn't show that it's a subgroup (it shows that, up to isomorphism it is, but here, what's wanted is more than just "up to isomorphism")

Comment: Then look at the set of cosets $K/H = \{kH \mid k\in K\}\subseteq \{gH \mid g\in G\}$

Comment: Yes I know how to do it, it was rather for the OP that I was saying that ;)

Comment: that's alright :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a problem defining things without making sure they do what you want, and making claims that you haven't verified to be true.

You can't just say "Let $\phi: G \to K$" or $\psi :K/H \to G/H$ without actually defining said homomorphisms (OK, you can, but you can't assume any properties of these maps without showing an arbitrary such map must indeed have these properties). In general, many  might exist, or they might have to be trivial. For instance, it's quite possible to have $H \lhd G$ and $H \lhd K \le G$, but for no surjective homomorphisms $\phi: G \to K$ to exist.

- As an example, take the normal Klein $4$-subgroup of $S_4$ to be $H$, take any subgroup isomorphic to the dihedral group with $8$ elements to be $K$, and $G$ to be $S_4$. If a homomorphism $\phi: S_4 \to D_4$ were to be subjective, its kernel would have to be a normal subgroup of order $3$, of which $S_4$ has none.

In addition, your map $\psi \circ \gamma \circ \phi$ can't be surjective unless $G = K$, since maps out of $K/H$ have images of size at most $[K:H] \le [G:H]$ (the index of $H$ in $K$ and $G$ respectively).